# Performance issue with mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am working in MYSQL for the first and I am having issues with the following query

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.name,
    t.description,
    
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( hs.name, '|', s.rate ) )
        FROM
            occupation_skill_rate s 
            INNER JOIN hard_skills hs ON s.hard_skill_id = hs.id
        WHERE
            s.occupation_id = t.id
        ORDER BY
            s.rate DESC LIMIT 15
    ) AS skills,

    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( hs.name, '|', s.rate ) )
        FROM
            occupation_knowledge_rate s 
            INNER JOIN knowledge hs ON s.knowledge_id = hs.id
        WHERE
            s.occupation_id = t.id
        ORDER BY
            s.rate DESC LIMIT 15
    ) AS knowledge,

    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( hs.name, '|', s.rate ) )
        FROM
            occupation_abilities_rate s 
            INNER JOIN ability hs ON s.ability_id = hs.id
        WHERE
            s.occupation_id = t.id
        ORDER BY
            s.rate DESC LIMIT 15
    ) AS knowledge

FROM
    occupations t
```

The occupation table contains 1033 rows occupation_skill_rate contains 34160 rows and it takes more than 1 minute to execute this query. Please let me know if you need further clarification for helping me.

[image]

Thanks for your help
Ajai

Comment: Post the `EXPLAIN`

Comment: See those ugly red boxes with "Full table scan" in them? That's why your query is slow. What `INDEX` objects do you have defined on those tables? Please show the **full** `EXPLAIN` output as that will show you what indexes you need to create.

Comment: Yeah you are correcr i added the index for occcupation_id column and now the full query runs under 1s approx 0.600s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `occupation_%_rate` tables seem to be many-to-many, correct?  They need these indexes and no id:

```
PRIMARY KEY(occupation_id, xxx_id)
INDEX(xxx_id, occupation_id)
```

But, it seems like the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` when used with `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  Please describe what the query's intention is; we may be able to help in rewriting it.

`GROUP_CONCAT` allows an `ORDER BY` clause but not a `LIMIT`.  Can you do without the `LIMITs`?

**Example**

Instead of

```
    ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( hs.name, '|', s.rate ) )
            FROM  occupation_skill_rate s
            INNER JOIN  hard_skills hs  ON s.hard_skill_id = hs.id
            WHERE  s.occupation_id = t.id
            ORDER BY  s.rate DESC
            LIMIT  15 
    ) AS skills;
```

Do

```
    ( SELECT  CONCAT( name, '|', rate ORDER BY  rate DESC )
            FROM (
                SELECT  hs.name, s.rate
                    FROM  occupation_skill_rate s
                    INNER JOIN  hard_skills hs
                          ON s.hard_skill_id = hs.id
                         AND s.occupation_id = t.id
                    ORDER BY  s.rate DESC
                    LIMIT  15
                 ) AS a 
    ) AS skills
```

But I suspect `t` is not visible that deeply nested.

If that is the case, rearrange things thus:

```
SELECT  t.id, t.name, t.description, s3.skills, ...
    FROM  occupations AS t
    JOIN (
        SELECT  s2.occupation_id,
                CONCAT( s2.name, '|', s2.rate ORDER BY  rate DESC )
                      AS skills
            FROM (
                SELECT  hs.name, s1.rate, s1.occupation_id
                    FROM  occupation_skill_rate s1
                    INNER JOIN  hard_skills hs
                           ON s1.hard_skill_id = hs.id
                    ORDER BY  s.rate DESC
                    LIMIT  15 
                 ) AS s2
            GROUP BY  s2.occupation_id
            ORDER BY  s2.rate DESC
         ) AS s3  ON s2.occupation_id = t.id
    JOIN  ...
    JOIN  ... ;
```

**Another**

There is also a way to build the long `GROUP_CONCAT`, then chop to 15 items by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(...)`.

Comment: Yes, i understand we can't use limit in a subquery. Does any other workaround? needs only 15 top rows from that subquery

Comment: I added more...